# SQLSTATE [42S02]: Base Table Or View Doesn't Exist Error

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-9

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'vy.views' doesn't exist

There is this Laravel project made by my friend, I am trying to use it. so he gave me the source code.

I extracted the zip.
then renamed the .env example to .env then modified a few things like engine ='InnoDB' & database name = vy. before this, I made sure composer was installed and then I installed filament. both were done. then I installed the npm node. then fixed npm issues with npm audit fix and ran npm run build which showed me some errors. but it's okay. then I tried to run the project by starting the server. but I was greeted with an error.

[image]

and yeah I migrated but there was an error. one table was not migrated. and the error is as follows in the migration.
**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'vy.activity_log' doesn't exist (SQL: alter table `activity_log` add `event` varchar(255) null after `subject_type`)**

[image]

I assume this error is the same error that is reflected on the home page of the project.

please I need to do this project. cause I have to make one more project like this. so I appreciate all ya help.

namaste from India.

I tried to run a project and was expecting it to run with no error

Comment: `database name = vy` Do you have database named `vy`?

Comment: You have better luck asking your friend who made the project. To me it looks like some Laravel libraries are missing (like e.g. activity-log) so their migrations do not run but your migrations assume that they have ran already.

Comment: yes i have the vy database ready. @Mr.Kenneth

Comment: @apokryfos it would be great if he could help. he made this project somehow and he didnot touched coding after this project,so he is giving me silly answers like i should delete database file.

Comment: For now, post the code in the failed migration file only (not image but actual code). Edit the question, Do not post as comment or new answer

Comment: i do not know how to open failed migration file. or it's location. or you mean i should ask a question here with that name ? kindly explain. or you mean i post migration file code here ? i don't know where the code of migration to find from. could you help with that so i can post here ?

Comment: What I meant is to post the code from migration file so that we can also check what the issue is. Migration files are located at `app\database\migrations\xxxx_yy_zz_aaaaaa_migrationfile.php`